# JAVA: Can java detect other 3rd party applications being open

Tags: java

I want to design a program that runs while another 3rd party application is running. For instance I want to keep looping the program while the skype window is open. Is this possible??

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        int right = InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK;
        int left = InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        robot.mouseMove(1720, 960);  
        robot.mousePress(right);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        robot.mouseRelease(right);
}
```

I want to loop this code while skype the window is open.

Comment: Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Again, please check out the links that I 've given to you in the comment above. There you'll learn that you shouldn't post code in comments where it cannot be formatted. Also, and again, you will want to provide more relevant detail on your problem and your code. Please also check out Jon Skeet's ["Stack Overflow question checklist"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) which can be useful when you want to write good question.

Comment: I have added code hopefully this clarifies

Comment: Thank you for the effort

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to see what application is still running;

```
String line = "";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
while ((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
    // now you can do what you want e.g: you can check the line if contains skype application name or other skype belongings information.
    System.out.println(line);
}
input.close();
```

The **output** of the program is:

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
Skype.exe                     9492 Console                    1    231,608 K
...
```

**So** inside `while-loop` you can check

```
if(line.toLowerCase().contains("skype")) {
    // do what you want if skype is running
} else {
    // do what you want if skype is not running
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: How does this work? I am pretty new to programming. How would I implement this to my current code?

Comment: Now look to the answer.